# disable the fixed manu that is lower than 980 px

Tags: javascript, html, css

Goal:
WHen I have a lower width for the browser (FF, IE and Chrome) that is lower than 980px, this fixed menu should not appear.

http://jsbin.com/pafasocuxe/edit?html,css,js,output

Quesion:
How should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a CSS Media Query to apply a style to hide the menu when the viewport is lower than 980px wide.

Adding this to your Stylesheet will take care of it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 979px){
  .nav-container{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

For more info on Media Queries: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp.
Either max-width 980px with display:none or have the non media style with display:none, and the media query with min-width and style with your normal display.